# how to pass props from a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can i pass props from a select component to my app js

here my code:

```html
const HandleSelect = ()=> {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState();

    return(
        <div className="App">
        <Select
          defaultValue={selectedOption}
          onChange={setSelectedOption}
          options={options}
        />
      </div>
    )
}
export default HandleSelect;
```

i've tried with

```html
const Select = (props) => {
    const {
        defaultValue, onChange, options
    } = props
    console.log(onChange);
    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}
export default Select
```

but in the app they return undefined when i try with console.log()

sorry for my english, i'm French.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The way you do its ok, you now have to print the values in the div in {} for example {defaultValue} Initialize your state to an empty string, it would also make more sense to log the defaultValue or selectedOptions instead of the onChange. Options its supposed to be an array also

Comment: Few things: check what `props` output with a `console.log`, i.e. test your assumptions, make sure you're passing down the prop values you're expecting. You might want to set a default state. The `onChange` prop your passing down is a (state) setter function, trying to log it out like a normal variable won't give you the result you expect. By the way, you don't want to hear my french.

Answer (score 2):

Destructure your props like this

```
const Select = ({defaultValue, onChange, options}) => {
    return (
        <div>
          <p>{defaultValue}</p>
          <p>{onChange}</p>
          <p>{options}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Select
```

or you could also do it this way

```
const Select = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
          <p>{props.defaultValue}</p>
          <p>{props.onChange}</p>
          <p>{props.options}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Select
```

Comment: Thanks! they returns:

Failed to compile

./src/component/select.js
SyntaxError: C:\Users\MegaS\Desktop\dashboard\src\component\select.js: Identifier 'Select' has already been declared (13:8)

Answer (score 0):

Here my app initial where i want to use the select, it's a lot of code, sorry for that !

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { FiPlusCircle } from 'react-icons/fi';
import { InputGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import ImageUpload from 'image-upload-react';
import { doc, setDoc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { decode as base64_decode, encode as base64_encode } from 'base-64';
import Select from './select';


// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const object1 = { title: 'Entrecôte', category: 'Viande', describe: 'Ici la description' };

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
    //my config
});

const db = getFirestore();

const Initial = (props) => {
    
    const [ data, setData ] = useState(object1);
    const [ loadata, setLoadata ] = useState();
    const [ imageSrc, setImageSrc ] = useState(); // form image source
    const [ encoded, setEncoded ] = useState(); // Value

    const [ title, setTitle ] = useState(''); // title
    const [ category, setCat ] = useState(''); // category
    const [ describe, setDesc ] = useState(''); // description

    const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
    const onSubmit = (data) => setData(data);

    // set url data
    const handleImageSelect = (e) => {
        setImageSrc(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data) {
            //form only
            setTitle(data.title);
            setCat(data.category);
            setDesc(data.describe);
            addTodo(title, category, describe, encoded); // great !
        }
    }, []);

    // write values to firebase database
    const addTodo = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(imageSrc);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            setEncoded(reader.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

        if (encoded && data) {
            await setDoc(doc(db, 'User', 'user000'), {
                category: category,
                title: title,
                describe: describe,
                image: encoded
            });
        }
    };

    function getScrollHeight(elm) {
        var savedValue = elm.value;
        elm.value = '';
        elm._baseScrollHeight = elm.scrollHeight;
        elm.value = savedValue;
    }
    function onExpandableTextareaInput({ target: elm }) {
        // make sure the input event originated from a textarea and it's desired to be auto-expandable
        if (!elm.classList.contains('autoExpand') || !elm.nodeName === 'TEXTAREA') return;

        var minRows = elm.getAttribute('data-min-rows') | 0,
            rows;
        !elm._baseScrollHeight && getScrollHeight(elm);

        elm.rows = minRows;
        rows = Math.ceil((elm.scrollHeight - elm._baseScrollHeight) / 16);
        elm.rows = minRows + rows;
    }

    // global delegated event listener
    document.addEventListener('input', onExpandableTextareaInput);

    // Ici je veux retourner le produit (lecture)
    const getUser = async () => {
        const list = [];
        const docRef = doc(db, 'User', 'user000');
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

        if (docSnap.exists()) {
            list.push(docSnap.data());
            const newlist = list[0];
            setLoadata(newlist);
        } else {
            console.log('No such document!');
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getUser();
    }, []);
// console.log('propsinou', props);
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid css-selector m-0 p-0" style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
            <div className="row m-0 p-0">
                <div className="col-12 row m-0">
                    {/* column card */}
                    <div className="col-md-1 cardColor mt-5 text-center text-white size">
                        <h4 className="mt-3 mb-4"> Bienvenue </h4>
                        <div className="round">
                            <FiPlusCircle size={40} />
                        </div>
                        <p>Ajouter menu</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-11 row space m-0 justify-content-center">
                        <h1 className="m-0 text-white text-center mt-5">Bienvenue sur votre Dashboard</h1>
                        <div className="col-10 row m-0">
                            <h4 className="m-0 text-white p-3">Étape 1 : ajouter du contenu </h4>
                            {/* First card */}
                            <div className="col-3 text-center card">
                                {loadata ? (
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <h3 className="m-0 text-success p-3">Titre</h3>
                                        <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                                            <InputGroup.Text id="basic-addon1"></InputGroup.Text>
                                            <FormControl
                                                placeholder={loadata.title}
                                                aria-label="Titre du menu"
                                                aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                                                {...register('title')} // onChange={e=>
                                                // this.setState({ val: e.target.value })}
                                            />
                                        </InputGroup>
                                        <h3 className="m-0 text-success">Catégorie</h3>
                                        <InputGroup className="mb-3 mt-3">
                                            <InputGroup.Text id="basic-addon1"></InputGroup.Text>
                                            <FormControl
                                                placeholder={loadata.category}
                                                aria-label="Username"
                                                aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                                                {...register('category')} // onChange={e=>
                                                //  this.setState({ val: e.target.value })}
                                            />
                                        </InputGroup>
                                    </div>
                                ) : (
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <h3 className="m-0 text-success p-3">Titre</h3>
                                        <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                                            <InputGroup.Text id="basic-addon1"></InputGroup.Text>
                                            <FormControl
                                                placeholder="titrent"
                                                aria-label="Titre du menu"
                                                aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                                                {...register('title')} // onChange={e=>
                                                // this.setState({ val: e.target.value })}
                                            />
                                        </InputGroup>
                                        <h3 className="m-0 text-success">Catégorie</h3>
                                        <InputGroup className="mb-3 mt-3">
                                            <InputGroup.Text id="basic-addon1"></InputGroup.Text>
                                            <FormControl
                                                placeholder="Username"
                                                aria-label="Username"
                                                aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                                                {...register('category')} // onChange={e=>
                                                // this.setState({ val: e.target.value })}
                                            />
                                        </InputGroup>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-3 card offset-1">
                                <div className="container">
                                    <h3 className="m-0 text-success p-3 text-center">Description</h3>
                                    {loadata ? (
                                        <textarea
                                            className="autoExpand"
                                            rows="3"
                                            data-min-rows="3"
                                            placeholder={loadata.describe}
                                            {...register('describe')}
                                            autoFocus
                                        />
                                    ) : (
                                        <textarea
                                            className="autoExpand"
                                            rows="3"
                                            data-min-rows="3"
                                            placeholder={'Entrez la description'}
                                            {...register('describe')}
                                            autoFocus
                                        />
                                    )}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-3 offset-1 p-absolute">
                                <ImageUpload
                                    className="border-r"
                                    handleImageSelect={handleImageSelect}
                                    imageSrc={imageSrc}
                                    setImageSrc={setImageSrc}
                                    style={{
                                        width: '100%',
                                        height: '100%',
                                        background: 'gold'
                                    }}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-10 row m-0">
                            <div className="col-3"></div>
                            <h4 className="m-0 text-white p-3 mt-5">Étape 2 : Choisir la catégorie & valider </h4>
                            {/* First card */}
                            <div className="col-3 text-center card">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <h3 className="m-0 text-success p-3">Catégorie</h3>
                                    <Select />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-3 offset-1 text-center card">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <h3 className="m-0 text-success p-3">Valider</h3>
                                    {/* <Button /> */}
                                    <Button variant="success" onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                                        Envoyer les données
                                    </Button>{' '}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {/* Boutton Select*/}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Initial;
```